# Default nested ui-views in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble with a simple ui-router sample I have set up.  I have a company page, whose default sub-state should show CompanyProfile, but it defaults to nothing until I click profile.  Once I clicked employees, I have to click profile twice to get it to show again.  Ideally I want `ui-sref="company()"` and `ui-sref="company.profile()"` to display the same screens.  It seems like I'm missing something small..

Here's the plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/A3LHGqQIuRlK1QdjuzrP?p=preview

HTML:

```
  <a ui-sref="company()">company</a>
  | <a ui-sref="company.profile()">profile</a>
  | <a ui-sref="company.employees()">employees</a>
```

JS:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('company', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'company.html',
        controller: 'CompanyCtrl as CompanyCtrl'
    })
    .state('company.profile', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'CompanyProfileCtrl as CompanyProfileCtrl'
    })
    .state('company.employees', {
        url: '/employees',
        templateUrl: 'employees.html',
        controller: 'CompanyEmployeesCtrl as CompanyEmployeesCtrl'
    });
```

btw, I'm writing everything as components and decided to define the routes in each component, so you'll find the 3 state definitions in the 3 controllers.  I'm not entirely sure this is the best approach or not yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default state is entirely dependent on how you call **[`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_otherwise)**, passing it a url transitions the application to the particular url, wherein `ui-router` detects and looks for the very first state it sees.

In your `main.js` configuration, defines the `/` url as the default url for the application, which is technically the `company` state's url and is the very first state in the chain of parent states and children states, making it the default state. This in fact, is also the resulting url for the `company.profile` state that you wanted your application to default to.

To solve this problem, depends on the use cases for your application.

1. Use case: If your application defines the `company` state as a non-navigational state, then setting it to an abstract state solves the problem.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IEpPYR3wTMW5kggBWpcm?p=preview)**

**CompanyCtrl.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('company', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'company.html',
        controller: 'CompanyCtrl as CompanyCtrl'
    });
```

2. Use case: If the `company` state is nagivational, then simply remove the `url` definition in the `company` state and change the `url` defintion for the `company.profile` state to `'/'`. The only caveat for this solution would be the loss of the `href` attribute to be applied for for any anchor tags defined with the `ui-sref="company"` state which also implies the application of the `text` cursor. To mitigate this problem you might as well define all `anchor` tags with `ui-sref` attribute with a `pointer` cursor.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Pk5I9xKHDLsHkOs7kLc?p=preview)**

**CompanyCtrl.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('company', {
        templateUrl: 'company.html',
        controller: 'CompanyCtrl as CompanyCtrl'
    });
```

**CompanyProfileCtrl.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('company.profile', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'CompanyProfileCtrl as CompanyProfileCtrl'
    })
```

**style.css**

```
a[ui-sref] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

3. Use Case: The same with use case #2 but making the `company` state an abstract state.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NlIt1GqtrLPtijwbjkuD?p=preview)**

**CompanyCtrl.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('company', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'company.html',
        controller: 'CompanyCtrl as CompanyCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, I was aware of the abstract concept, but `ui-sref="company"` fails navigation to an abstract route.  Removing the url from company fixes the defaulting issue, but still has the same navigation issue where I don't necessarily want anyone to navigate to `company()` without the profile being shown.  There is a concept of "Multiple Named Views", but I couldn't figure out how to fit this into my goal.  Are you intimately familiar with how they work? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Yes I am very familiar with multiple named views, but I don't think it is necessary for your case. Please check my update, `use case #3`.